# Illustrator - Minus Front command gives no results error

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon, pathfinder, shadows

I am creating an icon and to apply shadow I am using the method to create similar overlapping layer, shifting one layer a little bit, selecting both of them and using the Minus Front error. For the background rectangle this method worked like a charm. But for a png I imported, the command give me an error saying "The filter produced no results. Please select two intersecting paths." Why is this happening and how to solve this ?
[image]

If anything else needs to be included please do tell. I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZoRE9bv1mcc).

Comment: A linked entity is not a path

Comment: I want to use an external object (the face) in the icon and use minus front and the blend command (even blend is not working). How can I do this ?

Comment: you can not use minus front on external objects. Its not a question of want.

Comment: so how do I get the shadow, tint and elongated shadow on external object ?

Comment: You dont, if you want to work with the objets geometry thenyou need to expand it (if it is a vector image) or recreate it (if it is a bitmap), Or just draw the extre pieces manually.

Comment: What is the linked object?  If it's a raster image, then use Photoshop, not Illustrator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Illustrator's minus front not working?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/44642/why-is-illustrators-minus-front-not-working)

Comment: same commands but totally different issue. I know because before posting here I did quite a lot of research and did come across that question but it was not related to my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Minus Front function only works on paths. This is the same for all of the Pathfinder functions, hence the name.

In order to apply Pathfinder functions to a design that starts of as an image, as in this case, you first need to convert the design to paths. There are a couple of different ways to do this. You could look into using the **Image Trace** functionality in Illustrator or you might find that it's better to just redraw the item in question. The route that you take will depend on the complexity of the artwork in question and how skilled you are at drawing in Illustrator.

In either case, once you have paths, you can use the Pathfinder. However, the method that you are using will only work on one shape (or pair of shapes) at a time so you will have to deconstruct the design and apply the shadow effect individually for each part that you want to apply the effect to.